# Integrate Kal Calendar to My Tab Bar:

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I am developing an iPad application and relatively new in the business.
I am trying to integrate Kal Calendar into Tab item, that appear after logged into application.
But couldn't able to do so.

Comment: I would start by reading the instructions on the project's GitHub page (https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) and if you are still having difficulty after that, edit your question to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: show us what you have done so far, it could be problem in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to show a full screen view controller once a tab bar item is selected. You will want your tab bar item's view controller to be of type KalViewController. If you are doing this in interface builder with storyboards you would have a tab bar controller as your initial view and then drag a UIViewController onto the storyboard. Change that view controller's class to KalViewController and add it to the tab bar view controllers items.

If you are doing this in code, instantiate the KalViewController and add it to the UITabBarController's items:

```
KalViewController *kalVC = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
//set your tab bar's items, assuming you have a ref to the tab bar
tabBarController.tabBar setItems:@[kalVC,otherVC];
```